# jQuery: on blur move cursor to textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, setfocus

I am creating a simple todolist function. I have a textfield like so:

```
<input type="text" class="textbox">
```

on blur take value and append to:

```
<div class="outerbox"></div>
```

as:

```
<div class="box">value from textbox</div>
```

This is done in jQuery, now after this event I want to move the cursor back into the .textbox (on blur).

How can this be done ?

I tried  $('.textbox').focus(); which did'nt work..

Full code:

```
$(".textbox").blur(function(){

// 1. values
val = $(this).val();
time = '';

// 2. append
$(".outline").append('<div class="box"><div class="time">'+time+'</div>'+val+"</div>");


// 3. focus 
setTimeout(function(){$('.textbox').focus();},0);


});
```

Comment: Can you post your Jquery function

Comment: Well that sounds evil. How could you ever escape the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to break the callstack since you are trying to set focus on an element from inside it's blur event handler.

try to use

```
setTimeout(function(){$('.textbox').focus();},0);
```

it should do the trick for you

Comment: Ahh.. sorry it works.. problem is that it dosen't work on "tab" only if I point with my arrow somewhere else.. I guess I just need a special function for the "tab" key.. thanks, this solved it : )

Comment: You can set the timeout a little higher, maybe 50ms and then it should work for tab as well

Comment: Hmm ok, well my bet is the reason you have problems with tab is because tab sets focus on next tabindex and your call to focus clashes with the built in behaviour, so somehow you need to call your focus after tab is done.